# In SQL Server I have Json format rows in column level need to create multiple columns # fields are not order we can create based on that

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
{zipCode=47715, state=IN, city=Evansville, countryCode=US, line1=7424 Eagle Crest Blvd}
{zipCode=10965, state=NY, city=Pearl River, countryCode=US, line1=One Blue Hill Plaza}
{zipCode=30339, state=GA, city=Atlanta, countryCode=US, line1=1100 Circle 75 Parkway SE, Ste. 140}
{zipCode=35210, state=AL, city=Birmingham, countryCode=US, line1=700 Maple Street, Ste. B}
{zipCode=30339, state=GA, city=Atlanta, countryCode=US, line1=2839 Paces Ferry Road, Ste. 1200}
{zipCode=35242, state=AL, city=Birmingham, countryCode=US, line1=700 Corporate Parkway}
{zipCode=64112, state=MO, city=Kansas City, countryCode=US, line1=444 W 47th Street, Ste. 900}

line1
line2
line3
City
state
ZipCode
CountryCode

,CONVERT(VARCHAR(200),SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}',''), CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','') LIKE '%line1:%'                    THEN CHARINDEX('line1:'                                             ,REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 6        ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','') LIKE '%line2:%' THEN (CHARINDEX('line2:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) - 1) - (CHARINDEX('line1:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 6) WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','') LIKE '%line3:%' THEN (CHARINDEX('line3:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) - 1) - (CHARINDEX('line1:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 6) ELSE (CHARINDEX('state:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) - 1) - (CHARINDEX('line1:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 6) END)) AS mailing_address_line1
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(200),SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}',''), CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','') LIKE '%line2:%'                     THEN CHARINDEX('line2:'                                                ,REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 6        ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','') LIKE '%line3:%' THEN (CHARINDEX('line3:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) - 1) - (CHARINDEX('line2:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 6) ELSE (CHARINDEX('state:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) - 1) - (CHARINDEX('line2:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 6) END)) AS mailing_address_line2
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(200),SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}',''), CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','') LIKE '%line3:%'                     THEN CHARINDEX('line3:'                                                ,REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 6        ELSE NULL END, (CHARINDEX('state:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) - 1) - (CHARINDEX('line3:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 6))) AS mailing_address_line3
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}',''), CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','') LIKE '%city%'                                         THEN CHARINDEX(':'                                                                ,REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 1        ELSE NULL END, CHARINDEX(',',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) - (CHARINDEX(':',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 1)))AS mailing_address_city
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ,SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}',''), CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','') LIKE '%state:%'                     THEN CHARINDEX('state:'                                                ,REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 6        ELSE NULL END, (CHARINDEX('zipCode:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) - 1) - (CHARINDEX('state:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 6))) AS mailing_address_state
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50) ,SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}',''), CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','') LIKE '%zipCode:%'                               THEN CHARINDEX('zipCode:'                   ,REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 8        ELSE NULL END, (CHARINDEX('countryCode:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) - 1) - (CHARINDEX('zipCode:',REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 8))) AS mailing_address_zipcode
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ,SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}',''), CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','') LIKE '%countryCode:%'     THEN CHARINDEX('countryCode:'         ,REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')) + 12      ELSE NULL END, LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(Business_mailing_address,'{',''),'}','')))) AS mailing_address_countrycode
```

but how to after comma (,) space( ) how to give and handle Please help me out

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Valid JSON would have strings and key names in quotes `""`. If it was proper JSON you could use JSON functions to parse it. Are you using SQL Server 2008 or 2012, please only tag one.

Comment: This "JSON-like" format is inherently problematic and there's a reason JSON quotes things the way it does. You can't have *any* values with commas inside them with this approach without breaking the parsing in some way or another, for starters. The first thing you should investigate is what process is generating these values and why it's inserting them into a table with that specific format -- it may be possible to persuade the generating side to use something more stable, ideally breaking things down into columns and rows to begin with, but even XML would be better already.